# React Native: Module not found @react-native-community-cli

Tags: react-native

Project was working fine before I had to reinstall everything on my computer. I get the following error after I run `npm install` and then `expo start`

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:296
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/amber/Documents/GitKraken/school-notification-1/App/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:288:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:515:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amber/Documents/GitKraken/school-notification-1/App/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:12:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/home/amber/Documents/GitKraken/school-notification-1/App/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/package.json',
  requestPath: '@react-native-community/cli'
}

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
```

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/web": "^1.0.0-alpha.9",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "6.0.0",
    "navigationbar-react-native": "0.0.5",
    "qs": "^6.8.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-anchor-carousel": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.210.0",
    "react-native-circle-drawer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-drawer-menu": "^0.2.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^1.1.11",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-sidebar": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^34.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: did you install expo ?
npm install -g expo-cli

Answer (score 13):

Install this package.

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli
```

Comment: still not work on rn 0.68.2

Answer (score 3):

use npm install  @react-native-community-cli and run again, otherwise delete the package-lock.json and node_modules ,install npm again and please clean first before run the project

Comment: how to clean first.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, and then reran `npm install` and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `node_modules/` then run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : Might be off topic, related to AppCenter issue

If you got error `Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js'` in App Center build, then you need to:

1. Remove `@react-native-community/cli` from your `package.json`
2. Remove `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` (or `rm -rf yarn-lock.json && yarn`)
3. Push your changes to the branch and run App Center build

Hope it will help someone, since I didn't find any workaround for that issue