# Failed to construct transformer: Error: Cannot find module 'vue-native-scripts'

Tags: react-native, vue.js, npm, expo, vue-native

I am trying to install and run Vue-Native with Expo but I keep getting this error when open the expo app on my iphone

```
Metro has encountered an error: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined: Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js (95:34)

ABI43_0_0facebook::ABI43_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > ()>)
ABI43_0_0facebook::ABI43_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > ()>)
959CD6E4-0CE7-3022-B73C-8B36F79F4745
959CD6E4-0CE7-3022-B73C-8B36F79F4745
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
6174789A-E88C-3F5C-BA39-DE2E9EDC0750
6174789A-E88C-3F5C-BA39-DE2E9EDC0750
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
0E2D8679-D5F1-3C03-9010-7F6CE3662789
UIApplicationMain
Expo Go
start
```

I first ran `npm install --global vue-native-cli`

Next I ran `npm install --global expo-cli`

Followed by `vue-native init <projectName>`

Finally `cd <projectName>`

And `npm start`

I have tried uninstalling React, Expo, Vue-Native and reinstalling them.

Here is the error I get in the CLI

```
    Failed to construct transformer:  Error: Cannot find module 'vue-native-scripts'
Require stack:
- /Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/vueTransformerPlugin.js
- /Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
- /Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js
- /Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js
- /Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js
- /Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js
- /Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/metro/importMetroFromProject.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/HermesBundler.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/MetroDevServer.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/start/startDevServerAsync.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/internal.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/vueTransformerPlugin.js:1:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/vueTransformerPlugin.js',
    '/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js',
    '/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js',
    '/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js',
    '/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js',
    '/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js',
    '/Users/me/Documents/My Web/Rayrok/apps/the-bible/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/metro/importMetroFromProject.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/HermesBundler.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/MetroDevServer.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/start/startDevServerAsync.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/internal.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js'
  ]
}
iOS Bundling failed 21ms
Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I think the following might help in case anyone comes looking:

Install the following package:
`npm i @react-native-community/cli`

as described at this similar question.

[React Native: Module not found @react-native-community-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864453/react-native-module-not-found-react-native-community-cli)